# Sharing a DataFrame variable across packages in Apache Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I am developing a Spark app which basically process a DataFrame by calling many methods on it from several packages that I've created. However, I think it works quite slow (I provide 40 GB of RAM and there are only 4000 rows of data in the DataFrame that I use for testing, and it takes hours to complete).

I suspect that might be because of calling each method by value.

```
def any_method(data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) // a call-by-value definition
```

Could this be the source of slowness problem?

What is the correct practice of accessing the variable from different packages and methods?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by *sharing across packages*.

Comment: I have several packages which has some methods in them and in one of those packages I have a main method which has the mentioned DataFrame variable. I call those methods by importing the related package and passing the DataFrame variable by value. I'm talking about making this DataFrame variable accessible by any method under any package if possible. But also I am not sure that this is the reason of this slowness.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand anything from what you said. You are talking about scala packages ? passing DF is like passing any other value